# Find new values in a column with a datatype of list per row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Dataframe:

```
type  previous current
a     [1,2,3]  [1,2,3,5]
b     [1,2,3]  [1,2,3,9]
c     [1,2,3]  [1,2,3]
```

Hello there, i'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the unique value that is available in the current compared the previous column, is it possible what i'm trying?

Output:

```
type  result
a     5
b     9
c     0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach using `set`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"previous": [[1,2,3], [1,2,3], [1,2,3]], "current": [[1,2,3,5], [1,2,3,9], [1,2,3]]})
df['result'] = df['current'].apply(set)- df['previous'].apply(set)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
    previous       current result
0  [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3, 5]    {5}
1  [1, 2, 3]  [1, 2, 3, 9]    {9}
2  [1, 2, 3]     [1, 2, 3]     {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
y = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x=set(x)
y=set(y)
z = x.difference(y)
print(z)
#output 5, 6
```